# Employing a CDN for a dynamic website

Tags: performance, caching, cdn

I have a website forum where users exchange photos and text with one another on the home page. The home page shows 20 latest objects - be they photos or text. The 21st object is pushed out out of view. A new photo is uploaded every 5 seconds. A new text string is posted every second. In around 20 seconds, a photo that appeared at the top has disappeared at the bottom.

My question is: would I get a performance improvement if I introduced a CDN in the mix?

Since the content is changing, it seems I shouldn't be doing it. However, when I think about it logically, it does seem I'll get a performance improvement from introducing a CDN for my photos. Here's how. Imagine a photo is posted, appearing on the page at t=1 and remaining there till t=20. The first person to access the page (closer to t=1) will enable to photo to be pulled to an edge server. Thereafter, anyone accessing the photo will be receiving it from the CDN; this will last till t=20, after which the photo disappears. This is a veritable performance boost.

Can anyone comment on what are the flaws in my reasoning, and/or what am I failing to consider? Also would be good to know what alternative performance optimizations I can make for a website like mine. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider *all* requests hitting your server, which includes the primary dynamically generated HTML document, but also all static assets like CSS files, Javascript files and, yes, image files (both static and user uploaded content). An HTML document will reference several other assets, each of which needs to be downloaded separately and thus incurs a server hit. Assuming for the sake of argument that each visitor has an empty local cache, a single page load may incur, say, ~50 resource hits for your server.

Probably the only request which actually *needs* to be handled by your server is the dynamically generated HTML document, if it's specific to the user (because they're logged in). **All other 49 resource requests are identical for all visitors and can easily be shunted off to a CDN.** Those will just hit your server once [per region], and then be cached by the CDN and rarely bother your server again. You can even have the CDN cache *public* HTML documents, e.g. for non-logged in users, you can let the CDN cache HTML documents for ~5 seconds, depending on how up-to-date you want your site to appear; so the CDN can handle an entire browsing session without hitting your server at all.

If you have roughly one new upload per second, that means there is likely a magnitude more passive *visitors* per second. If you can let a CDN handle ~99% of requests, that's a *dramatic* reduction in actual hits to your server. If you are clever with what you cache and for how long and depending on your particular mix of anonymous and authenticated users, you can easily reduce server loads by a magnitude or two. On the other side, you're speeding up page load times accordingly for your visitors.

For every single HTML document and other asset, really think whether this can be cached and for how long:

- For HTML documents, is the user logged in? If no, and there's no other specific cookie tracking or similar things going on, then the asset is static and public for all intents and purposes and can be cached. Decide on a maximum age for the document and let the CDN cache it. Even caching it for just a second makes a giant difference when you get 1000 hits per second.
- If the user *is* logged in, set the cache pragma to `private`, but still let the visitor's browser cache it for a few seconds. These headers must be decided upon by your forum software while it's generating the document.
- For all other assets which aren't access restricted: let the CDN cache it for a *long* time and you can practically forget about ever having to serve those particular files ever again. These headers can be statically configured for entire directories in the web server.

Answer (score 2):

You've got it right. As long as someone accesses the photo within the 20 seconds that the image is within view it will be pulled to an edge server. Then upon subsequent requests, other visitors will receive a cached response from the nearest edge server.

As long as you're using the CDN for delivering just your static assets, there should be no issues with your setup.

Additionally, you may want to look into a CDN which supports HTTP/2. This will provide you with improved performance. Check out [cdncomparison.com](http://cdncomparison.com/) for a comparison between popular CDN providers.